# Failed parsing json to class

Tags: c#, json, parsing, xamarin.forms

I have a problem. I am parsing json that I receive from my webpage to a class. Here is my code:

```
public class Root
{
    public User user { get; set; }
    public Token token { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
}

public class Token
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public int expire_in { get; set; }
    public DateTime expire_date { get; set; }
}
```

With the deserialize:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

And here is my json:

```
{"user":[[{"Id":"0","Username":"Vreesie","ProfilePicture":""}]],"token":[[{"access_token":"zPEfybcHy48uLlD0lJJntKplM8I7XBplujTLFs7f","refresh_token":"xh2vtwzROSDTK3JjA7OJOwUc9lY6q0SYCwyYcOVU","expires_in":3600}]]}
```

But when I run the code, I get the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'MyApp.Models.User'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly.

I already tried to set the json in a JObject, but still the same error?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "user" from your JSON is an array of an array of objects.  Your structure does not match that.

Comment: Your json does not match your C#.  Both "user" and "token" are arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your classes the following way. Set up User and Token like a `List<List<>>` .

```
public class Root
{
    public List<List<User>> user { get; set; } // LIST OF LIST OF USER
    public List<List<Token>> token { get; set; } // LIST OF LIST OF TOKEN
}
```

**REASON**  Since your json shows user to be a list of a list of users and token to be a list of list of tokens, you need to set up the object like that as well.

When I tried to deserialize this, it worked fine.

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```